# jQuery image slider in a Foundation 5 modal not working w/ dynamic data

Tags: php, jquery

I'm building a car and car parts website. The cars are displayed on the page in styled boxes with one photo and a brief description, all data coming from the database. There's a button to display all the corresponding car's photos in a drop down [reveal modal](http://www.jssor.com/demos/image-gallery.html) that displays a [jQuery photo slider w/ thumbnails](http://www.jssor.com/demos/image-gallery.html).

It works fine hard-coded but the image slider images don't show up in the modal whenever the data comes from a call to the database. Strangely if you copy and paste the html being generated by the PHP script into the page, it works perfectly fine and the images load from the db into the slider. I copied the generated HTML from Firefox' developer toolbar otherwise it doesn't show up in the regular 'view source'. Is that the problem?

Briefly, I used the onload event in the body tag to call the AJAX/PHP , get the data from the DB and display all the cars in their boxes, including all the attribute values being passed to the modal:

```
...data-reveal-id="sliderModal" data-my-name="67camaro/Camaro">
```

I use some jQuery to loop thru the image folder URL and append a number and `'.jpg'` to the end of the img's base name and push it into the slider's img src:

```
jq("#image0" + i).attr("src", newText) ;
```

I even used `$.noConflict()` on the above code to make sure it wasn't conflicting w/ JSSOR's jQuery slider, to no avail.

I've searched and read everything but I'm not finding anyone else w/ the same problem. I'm a bit of a newb still and I've reached my ceiling on this prob. There's a ton of code that comes w/ the slider more than the limit apparently.

Comment: var jq = $.noConflict();

Comment: can you reproduce the error in a JSFIDDLE?

Comment: here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DuckofDeath/ek109qwo/     I put the php code in the CSS box and only included the relevant HTML. Again, the html being generated by the php script works if you copy and paste it in perfectly and all images load in the slider.

Comment: Not really sure how to reproduce error in jsfiddle when it all depends on server scripting and images.

Comment: Here's a link:http://www.modernmediaworld.com/diaboli/diaboliDB2.php   the first two cars are hard coded and the slider galleries in the modal works fine. The bottom two are generated by PHP/AJAX and even though the html code generated by it is the same as the first two hard coded ones, the modal comes down without images. PS if you click on the first two before the PHP/AJAX generated ones at bottom, the previous images will still be in the modal from memory....don't be fooled by this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks you have used direct event instead of delegated events.

Direct events will be assigned only to the elements which are already present in `document` object where as delegated events will work for old as well any newly added elements

```
jq('[data-reveal-id]').on('click', function() { // In this line you are registering direct event handlers
        var targetModal = jq('#' + jq(this).data('revealId'));
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            var newText = 'img\/' + jq(this).data('myName') + '0' + i + '.jpg';
                jq("#image0" + i).attr("src", newText) ;
                jq("#thumb0" + i).attr("src", newText) ;              
        }
        for (var i = 9; i < 16; i++){
            var newText = 'img\/' + jq(this).data('myName')  + i + '.jpg';
                jq("#image" + i).attr("src", newText) ;
                jq("#thumb" + i).attr("src", newText);              
        }         
    });
```

To use delegated events you should change

```
jq('[data-reveal-id]').on('click', function() {
```

to

```
jq(document).on('click','[data-reveal-id]', function() {
```

You can change `document` to any element which is parent to `[data-reveal-id]`

One more error i was able to find is, the url present in `data-my-name` of newly added elements are wrong

expected url is `68convertible/convert` and the url which you are passing is `/img/68convertible/convert`

To know more about Delegate events and `on` function see [this](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.The value for 'data-my-name' is generated by database and PHP and is the images' folder and the base image name. The jquery code appends the "img/" portion of the image url and then the image number plus image format, "01.jpg" and pushes it to '<img u="image" id="image01" src="" />'...this is correct url isn't it? img u="image" id="image01" src="img/68convertible/convert01.jpg".I'm going to try this as soon as I can, unfortunately i had problems uploading php files to my server and when they fixed it,I found all my php scripts were blank.So angry.

Comment: Yeah correct. Your jquery code ill append `img/` but your `data-my-name` attribute is already having `img/68convertible/convert`. So if you append now, url ill become `img/img/68convertible/convert`.

Comment: I forgot to removed that before I posted it...had fixed it but it didnt fix problem. now is written as: var newText =  jq(this).data('myName')  + i + '.jpg'; still doesn't work

Comment: Weirdly enough the 'no conflict()' conflicted with my form submission code and I had to get rid of it and go back to '$' or the confirmation modal does not pop up.

Comment: try using `jQuery` instead of `$`